# IE7 - display: block <a> within <li> does not display correctly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

If you look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/b3KaM/2/

in IE7 the `<a>` tags do not stretch to their parent `<li>` width even if `display: block;` is set. You can see the difference with the background color set to red on the list items and yellow on the links.

it obviously work fine in FF/Chrome & friends.

EDIT:
the complication here is that I cannot set a fixed width - the link text should stay on one line and the whole list should expand as needed.

I'm aware that this as been asked before and I've found a few questions on SO but I could not find a valid solution to this issue - any ideas anyone?

If not - is it safe to say that is not possible to achieve the same result on IE7 as on other browsers, i.e. it's an Internet Explorer bug with no workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by a rendering phenomenon in IE7 and lower [known as `hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

To fix the problem, you must simply prevent your `a` elements from "gaining layout".

Unfortunately, there's [massive list of stuff that causes an element to "gain layout"](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html#prop).

Your `a` elements currently have `overflow: hidden` and `min-height` set. If you remove those properties, it will work in IE7.

Comment: Here's a quick demo with those things commented out: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/b3KaM/14/. It now works in IE7, but obviously it's now slightly visually broken. Hopefully you can make it look right again, without breaking the "rules of hasLayout".

Comment: thanks, in my environment, it does break things even more than what's shown on the fiddle - nevertheless you've demonstrated that your answer works for the specific so I will +1 and accept your answer - first time ever that I DIDN'T want to trigger hasLayout!

Answer (score 0):

With block you have to give the width also for the element.For example:- http://jsfiddle.net/b3KaM/8/

Comment: Thanks, I've thought about this but I forgot to mention that I should not set a width as the link text should stay on one line.

Comment: Not true is it?  That's float, not block, where you should give a width.